window.opener is null after window.open()
I've got an application on which the login should go through an external website and then redirect to my application.
The external website is opened from localhost on a pop-up, with this line :
window.open(result.data.redirect, "_blank", "menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no");

Once the user is connected, the pop-up redirects to a page on the localhost. That page is supposed to send a message to its parent so that the rest of the process can be done :
const parent = window.opener;
parent.postMessage(obj, "*");

But window.opener is null and I don't understand why. There are other ways of connecting through a pop-up like that (opening the pop-up to another website and then redirecting to localhost) and they work well. I've read a lot of SO posts about this but none helped me.
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Is the messaged being posted from the 3rd party login origin, or does that origin redirect back to your page?

@a7md0 the 3rd party redirects back to my page, and that page is supposed to send a message (using postMessage) to the parent window
